# v2 format issue in deleting a particular row in kusto Table

Tags: kql

I am trying to delete a particular row from kusto table using the below query.

```
.delete table <TableName> records with (whatif = true) <|
Rescue_Table
| where <columnName> == "Testing" ;
```

I haven't use V2format during insertion
**Insert query:**

```
.ingest inline into table <TableName> <|\r<value1>,<value2>
```

But I am getting the below issue
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `.delete` command is only possible in services that are using [engine v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/Engine-v3).
You'll need to migrate to that in order for it to work.

If you're not sure how to do so, you should open a support ticket for your resource.